# go and dynamo get data from table where field in list and field is not null / field is not empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Do you know how to make a get or delete call with a "field in list" (example: " type in ('first','primero','base')")? (In dynamo-goLang, please.)

The following code works:

```
input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String(myTableName),
    Key: map[string]dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "id": {
            S: aws.String(positionId),
        },
        "type": {
            S: aws.String('first'),
        },
    },
}
```

But I would like to make a get data from a list of types (where type is in list), or where type is not null or is not empty.

Example in sql of what I intend to do in dynamo-goLang:

```
SELECT * FROM myTableName WHERE id = positionId AND type IN ('first','primero','base');
```

AND

```
SELECT * FROM myTableName WHERE id = positionId AND type IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple results where you specify the partition key and you want to filter by the sort key, you want to use [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.Query) instead of GetItem.

Some resources with examples as my golang is a little rusty:

- https://github.com/markuscraig/dynamodb-examples/blob/master/go/movies_query_year_title.go
- https://medium.com/@spiritualcoder/step-by-step-guide-to-use-dynamodb-with-golang-cd374f159a64

Comment: Hi. Aren't partition and hash key the same thing? Also are you sure that that `type` is the sort key in the OP's case?

Comment: oops, I mean sort instead of hash, too many 4 letter words :).  I am not sure if `id` or `type` is partition vs sort but hopefully he can clarify if my assumption is incorrect.

Also, congrats on the recent gold AWS badge, thanks for all of your support in the community, maybe I can get one of those in a couple of years :)

Comment: No problem and thanks. You will get there. Step by step :-)